# How to share a lightning email template folder?

Tags: email-template, sharing, folder

I'm trying to find the screen where you can share lightning email template folders with other users but can't see it anywhere. It's mentioned in here so I know it exists: 
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_sales_productivity_email_templates_share.htm

Can anyone tell me where it is?

I have enabled the org setting "Folders and Enhanced Sharing for Lightning Email Templates" and assigned myself a permission set allowing me to share lightning email template folders.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[instanceURL]/lightning/r/Folder/[folderId]/view?queryScope=userFolders

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but for anyone who's also looking for the sharing option when you get to the folder list:

[image: Sharing a folder]